# How to initialize a treeview control defined in JavaFX fxml file by code

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

The effect I want to achieve is as follows, all created by code.
[image]

The code is as follows，This method can achieve the result I want because in the start method, first initialize treeview, then create a scene, add it in, and then display it successfully. Example1：

```
public class treeViewDemo_4 extends Application {

    // Node图标
    private final Node rootIcon = new ImageView(
        new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon/file.png"))
    );

    private TreeView<String> createTreeView(TreeItem<String> root1,TreeItem<String> root2) {
        TreeItem<String> dummyRoot = new TreeItem<>();
        dummyRoot.getChildren().addAll(root1,root2);
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(dummyRoot);
        tree.setShowRoot(false);
        return tree ;
    }

    final TreeItem<String> root1 = new TreeItem<>("root 1");
    final TreeItem<String> root2 = new TreeItem<>("root 2");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
        // 每个Item下又可以添加新的Item
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<> ("Message" + i);
            item.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("第三级"));
            root1.getChildren().add(item);
        }
        // 创建TreeView
        TreeView<String> tree = createTreeView(root1,root2);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

But I want to achieve this effect through the fxml file, but I don't know how. First of all, my code, Example2：

fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:controller="com.fendo.flying.demo.treeview.demo5.demo5Controller" fx:id="rootPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="705.0" prefWidth="1113.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
   <children>
       <TreeView fx:id="treeView" layoutX="3.0" layoutY="94.0" prefHeight="608.0" prefWidth="214.0">

       </TreeView>
      <Button layoutX="300.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="715.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="597.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="393.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="492.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

controller

```
public class demo5Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TreeView treeView;

    final TreeItem<String> root1 = new TreeItem<>("root 1");
    final TreeItem<String> root2 = new TreeItem<>("root 2");
    final TreeView<String> tree = createTreeView(root1,root2);

    private TreeView<String> createTreeView(TreeItem<String> root1,TreeItem<String> root2) {
        TreeItem<String> dummyRoot = new TreeItem<>();
        dummyRoot.getChildren().addAll(root1,root2);
        TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>(dummyRoot);
        tree.setShowRoot(false);
        return tree ;
    }


    public demo5Controller() {
        treeView = createTreeView(root1,root2);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        treeView = createTreeView(root1,root2);
    }
}
```

Example2 Invalid after run. Treeview did not initialize successfully, display is empty ,What I want to know is how to initialize treeview defined in fxml through code?

Or, I defined a treeview in fxml. How to initialize or overwrite it in controller? To achieve the effect in example 1

How to make the implementation in example 2, that is, the effect of the following code in example 1:

```
// create TreeView
TreeView<String> tree = createTreeView(root1,root2);

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(tree);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Still not quite sure what you are after and where the problem is (except your error of manually instantiating an injected field - which you __must not do__, never-ever). BTW, I think it's time for reading and understanding a basic tutorial on fxml ... and learn and use those darn naming  conventions __now__!

Answer (score 4):

To create and configure a TreeView completely by fxml, add the treeItem structure inside your `<TreeView>` tag, basically something like:

```
<TreeView fx:id="treeView"> 
      <TreeItem value = "treeRoot" expanded="true">
            <children>
                <TreeItem value="firstChild" />
                <TreeItem value="secondChild" />
            </children>
      </TreeItem>
</TreeView>
```

For deeper nesting, do the same for the child items.

To create the TreeView by fxml and configure its content by code, do the latter in the controller's initialize (important: **do not** instantiate the treeView manually!)

```
@FXML private TreeView<String> treeView;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    treeView.setRoot(createItemHierarchy(new TreeItem<String>("root1"), new TreeItem<String>("root2")));
}

private TreeItem<String> createItemHierarchy(TreeItem<String>... root1) {
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("base root");
    root.getChildren().addAll(root1);
    return root ;
}
```

Comment: This is not the effect I want. What I want is to initialize treeview through code createtreeview (root1, root2),

Comment: ehh .. then what do you mean by _But I want to achieve this effect through the fxml file, but I don't know how to achieve it_ Please edit your question and clarify which part exactly you can't do (in particular, remove everything unrelated ...)

Comment: Thank you. I know through the way of fxml. What I want to achieve is to initialize the treeview defined in fxml through createtreeview (root1, root2) in the initialize method. As shown in the code, it has no effect. What I want to ask is, what else can I do to initialize the control defined in fxml in the code?

Comment: @kleopatra maybe he is asking how to call `createTreeView` from FXML. `fx:factory` might be the thing he is looking for.

Comment: @M.S. why would anybody go such a winded path when configuring (either in fxml or in code) the injected treeView would achieve the same? At OP: change the nam/signature of the method to `TreeItem createRoot(..)` and let it return the item hierarchy .. and don't forget to clarify your question!

Comment: @kleopatra I couldn't agree more but I was trying to understand the OP's question.

Comment: @M.S. okay, just thought I missed something obvious :) Nothing much to do without further clarification from OP (in the question, not here as a comment!)

Comment: I changed the question. Thank you very much

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you. That's exactly what I want

Comment: @laram if the provided answer works for you - please consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.